# Is there a way to tell which child class called a parent's function in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child

I have two classes that are extending the same class, for example:

```
abstract class A {
//functions
}
class B extends A {
//functions
}
class C extends A {
//functions
}
```

I would like a function in the parent class to change it's behavior depending on which child class is calling the function, for example, a function in class A will execute a different if statement depending on which child class calls the function. Is there a way for the parent class to know which child constructor is using it's function?

Comment: `this.getClass()`

Comment: Another option is to use `instanceof`: `if (this instanceof B) {}`

Comment: If I had to do something like this I might rethink my design.  Otherwise, you may have problems when you need to subclass the parent in the future.  Would it not better to simply override the method in the subclass with the subclass' requirements?

Comment: Exactly so. This technique is known as 'state orientation' and it was discarded as poor practice in the 1960s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing, here you go:

```
abstract class A {
// abstract functions
public void myCoolFunction(){
    if(this.getClass().equals(B.class)){
      System.out.println("B!");
    }else{
      System.out.println("NOT B!");
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
//functions
}

class C extends A {
//functions
}
```

Testing it:

```
jshell> C c = new C();
c ==> C@6d4b1c02

jshell> c.myCoolFunction();
NOT B!

jshell> B b = new B();
b ==> B@4883b407

jshell> b.myCoolFunction();
B!
```

By the way this kind of technique is usually a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) or bad design.

Comment: Or to demo, just `System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());`

Comment: BTW, this is, IMHO, hideously bad design. I hope that this is just out of curiosity, and not intended for actual use.

Comment: Agreed. Added a final note to make it clear.